# Until user input equals something do - Follow up

Tags: shell, variables, input

Following up on someone else's question titled "Until user input equals something do". My script asks user for a filename. The script must search for the file. If the file does not exist in the directory, user must again be prompted for filename until they enter file that exists (must persist until true, without exiting program). Would it look something like?:

```
printf "Enter filename: "
read ifile
while [[ ! -e "$ifile" ]]
do
  printf "File $ifile not found! "
done
```

When a file that does not exist is entered, I get a "runaway" loop until I have to cancel (CNTL + C). Example: If file filesa exists, but user "fat-fingers" it as filessa

Enter filename: filessa
File filessa not found! File filessa not found! File filessa not found! File filessa not found! File filessa not found! File filessa not found! ...........on and on and on.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `until` loop in `bash`:

```
until [[ -e $ifile ]]; do
    [[ -z $ifile ]] || printf "File $ifile not found!\n"
    read -p "Enter filename: " ifile
done
```

Actually, `until` is part of the POSIX standard as well, although a POSIX-compliant example would be less concise:

```
until [ -e "$ifile" ]; do
    [ -z "$ifile" ] || printf "File $ifile not found!\n"
    printf "Enter filename: "
    read ifile
done
```

Comment: Until loop worked nicely! can you explain the this part:

    [ -z "$ifile" ]

Many thanks!

Comment: It checks if the expansion of `$ifile` is an empty string. `ifile` will be empty the first time through the loop (technically, unset, if you don't initialize it to something else first) and if the user just hits Enter without typing anything following the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
printf "Enter filename: "
read ifile
while [[ ! -e "$ifile" ]]
do
  printf "File $ifile not found! \n"
  printf "Enter filename: "
  read ifile
done
```

If the user has entered the wrong filename, then you have to ask them to try again ;-).

Also, if the user doesn't enter anything, that will produce a different error.
I would write the more extended check as

```
printf "Enter filename: "
read ifile
while [[ ! -e "${ifile:-XXXXno_user_inputXXXX}" ]]
do
  printf "File ${ifile:-XXXXno_user_inputXXXX} not found! \n"
  printf "Enter filename: "
  read ifile
done
```

The var syntax `${var:-defaultValue}` can be read as "if the variable `$var` is empty, then print the value after the `:-` as a replacement value.

A pedantic objection to `XXXXno_user_inputXXXX` is that it's possible that there might be a file in your directory already named `XXXX_no_user_inputXXXX`, so you'll have to decide if that is a big risk for your project.

IHTH

Comment: thank you! that did the trick. also, when i run a test where user enters nothing (Enter key) or blank (space, then Enter) without the extended check, the script behaves the same as when file name entered does not exist. I see the benefit of having the -defaultValue, just puzzled why when  run without it in my test a null value was treated the same as a file that does not exist. is it needed?

Comment: The `-e` tests for a file;s existence. So for that test, a misspelled filename doesn't exist, and `""` doesn't exist either. You could see it as a good, bare-bones check that does both input validation and file existence checking. Glad this helped. Please accept that answer then best answers your question and upvote any answer that helped you understand shell scripting ;-) . Good luck to all.